# Correct way to draw the diagram using circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Can any one draw this circuit using `circuitikz`?

[image]

I have drawn the figure but I don't know how to draw the arrow above the two ports as in the diagram.

```
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) to [twoport,t=G,v^<= .] (2,0) (2,0) -- (4,0)node[anchor=west]{AG} (2,0) |- (4,-1)node[anchor=west]{AG} (-1,0)node[anchor=east]{A} --(0,0) (6,-0.5)node[]{\Large$\Rightarrow$} (8,0)node[anchor=east]{A} (9,0) (10,0) to [twoport,t=G] (12,0)node[anchor=west]{AG} (10,-1.5) to [twoport,t=G] (12,-1.5)node[anchor=west]{AG} (8,0) -- (10,0) (9,0) |- (10,-1.5) ; 
\end{circuitikz}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! of course here around are many people who know how to draw this schema, however, this is not site with service "we-will-your-task-instead-of-you". so, first you show, what you try so far in where you stuck in your effort, second, for showed images  `circuitikz` is not the best tool.

Comment: So, as @Zarko says, help us help yourself and read the tutorial of the TikZ manual. It's a worth effort and you'll learn how to do your diagram. Meanwhile, the `circuitikz` tag is pllain wrong...

Comment: i have drawn the figure but i don't know how to draw arrow above the two port as in the diagram.

Comment: \begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) to  [twoport,t=G,v^<= .] (2,0)
(2,0) -- (4,0)node[anchor=west]{AG}
(2,0) |- (4,-1)node[anchor=west]{AG}
(-1,0)node[anchor=east]{A} --(0,0)
(6,-0.5)node[]{\Large$\Rightarrow$}
(8,0)node[anchor=east]{A} (9,0)
(10,0) to  [twoport,t=G] (12,0)node[anchor=west]{AG}
(10,-1.5) to  [twoport,t=G] (12,-1.5)node[anchor=west]{AG}
(8,0) -- (10,0)
(9,0) |- (10,-1.5)
;
\end{circuitikz}

Comment: `\draw[latex-,thick,dashed] (1,1) arc[start angle=90, end angle=180,radius=1cm] -- (0,0);
\draw[thick,dashed] (2,0) arc[start angle=0, end angle=90,radius=1cm] -- (1,1);
`

Comment: While dashed or dotted lines and arcs are not covered in the circuitikz manual, you also need the tikz manual.